# Oracle Apex: Definition Name already exists

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I created a `Data Load` page with name `Load Tasks`. I make some mistakes so rather than troubleshooting through the entire thing, I decided to delete and recreate. When going through the `Create Data Load Wizard`, I can't reuse the name definition `Load Tasks` giving me the error `Definition Name already exists`.

How can I clean up so I can reuse the Definition Names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a Data Load page using the wizard, it creates a Data Load Definition as well. If you delete the pages but not the definition, you will get this error if you try to recreate it.

Go to your application's **Shared Components**, and click **Data Load Definitions**. I expect you will find it there - you can delete it from there.